# Determine numbers based on their sum and xor

Tags: algorithm, xor

If we know the sum and XOR of two numbers, then can we find out what are the two numbers?

I am trying to resolve a problem and the above problem is a part of that. Although, I do have another solution for that problem but I still want a solution for this.

Comment: This looks somewhat like homework (which we will not solve for you).. please show us what you have got so far and we'll be happy to help you out.

Comment: I just to want know if that's possible then I will apply some more effort.

Comment: You can't. For example, take `x + y == 3, x ^ y == 3`, now you can take `x = 0, y = 3`, `x = 1, y = 2` (or swap `x` and `y`)

Comment: @harold Let A and B are the two nos. If I take the complement of XOR and then subtract the complement of Sum from it then I will get the product of AB. Now, I have the product and the sum of 2 nos and I can easily get the answer.

Comment: @user2677679 no you can't, I just proved you can't. You can get *some* solution of course, and in some cases there is only one solution, but often there are multiple solutions and then you can't know which one of those represents the original two numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Example: SUM=7, XOR=7
Possible answers:
a) 1, 6
b) 2, 5
c) 3, 4

Not enough information to decide which pair (a, b or c) is the original pair of numbers.