# Is it possible to solve X and Y knowing X^Y and X+Y?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am trying to solve this leetcode problem:
[Given an array of numbers nums, in which exactly two elements appear only once and all the other elements appear exactly twice. Find the two elements that appear only once.](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/)

I know the standard solution is to compute X^Y, and get the lowest uncommon bit, ...

But I also have another idea:

I can get X^Y by XOR all the numbers;

```
xored = 0
for i in nums:
   xored  = xored^i
```

I can also get X+Y by adding each binary bit of the numbers individually, and modular 2.

```
# pseudo-code
bitvector = [0]* number of bits of integer
for n in numbers:
   for bit in bitvector:
       bitvector[i] += n[bit]
       bitvector[i] = bitvector[i]%2
```

But I don't know how to get X and Y, with X+Y and X^Y, or even if this is possible.

Can you help?

Comment: no you cant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565626/determine-numbers-based-on-their-sum-and-xor

Comment: Try solving X^Y = X+Y = 1111b and see for yourself.

Comment: How stupid of me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Bitwise XOR is just addition without carry. You can easily build counter-examples:

```
 x   01   11
 y   10   00
xor  11   11
```

`1 + 2`, `3 + 0` and `1 ^ 2`, `3 ^ 0` all have the same result.

Comment: `2+2 == 4 + 0` but `2^2 != 4^0`. Addition is xor with carry.

Comment: @amit My point is, given `x + y == 3` and `x ^ y == 3`, it's not possible to get a unique answer.

Comment: I am nitpicking the wording in the explanation, not the concept of the answer or the example.